# facebook: preview News Feed stories created when publishing actions

Tags: facebook, logging, android-activity, facebook-timeline

I'm looking for a simple way to show the user some actions she has generated using my app.

It should look like the recent activity ticker displayed (RecentActivityUnit) in the timeline but only with some certain actions decided by the app and, most important, it should allow to remove the action (so activity feed plugin is not suitable)

First idea is to:

1. query opengraph to get desidered actions,
2. get related open graph objects
3. use facebook internationalization feature for displaying action.

Is it really what facebook does when it builds the activity log (or ) ?
Does anybody know a simpler way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is the only way to do such a thing. If you know the Action IDs in advanced, you can skip the first step and simply search for the actions you need in Step 2.

Internationalization is only required if your site supports multiple languages. If it's for an app within Facebook, then this is recommended since users could be using your app in other languages.